# Unable to boot/mount Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

So, I am trying to install Ubuntu Version 12.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire Series 5742Z running Windows 7 Home Premium.

To accomplish this, I carried out the following steps:

I went into the Windows partition settings, and shrank the (C:) Volume (type NTFS) in order to create a new partition of 127.96GB (L: - also type NTFS) on which I would install the Linux software with 156.03GB remaining on the C: drive to keep Windows on a separate partition.

After this, I downloaded Ubuntu using the Windows Installer version (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), while specifying the L: drive and size for installation.

Now, when I boot up the laptop, I am given the choice between Windows 7 and Ubuntu (as one would expect). However, when I select Ubuntu, the following error message flashes:

Hd(0.0): NTFS5: No wubuildr

Hd(0.1): NTFS5: No wubuildr

Hd(0.2): NTFS5: error: “prefix” is not set

After this, a purple interface will appear stating “Preparing Ubuntu for first time use”. However, I then get the message “An error occured while mounting”. Please note that while I am currently trying a desktop installation, I have tried to mount Ubuntu from a USB stick as well prior to this method, and that has brought no joy either.

Any ideas? I really want to switch over due to my increasing dissatisfaction (to put it mildly) with Windows. Any help or expertise would be greatly appreciated; should you require any further information I’ll gladly pass it on! Also, please note that I am quite new to coding, programming etc so if there are complex steps required I’d be grateful if you could please explain it in layman terms. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you download the full installer and follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: I have done the steps outlined, including booting from a CD Rom. However, I now have a new problem. I can now only "try" the Ubuntu software; when I want to install it fully I am continuously getting the following error message: "Installation crashed". On one occasion, I also got the accompanying error message: "Error 30 - Read only file system". Would be grateful for any assistance.